# Django Serializer for post with related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have the following Models and Serializer:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    orderType = models.IntegerField()
    justification = models.CharField("Order justification", max_length=150, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Order date")
    
    status = OrderType()

class Item(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemsProduct')
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity sale")
    price = models.DecimalField("Sale price", max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)


class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    items = ItemSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        depth = 0
        fields = ["user", "orderType", "justification", "date", "items"]
```

I want realize a post with a json like this:

```
{
  "user": 10,
  "orderType": 1,
  "justification": "",
  "date": "2020-09-30T19:11:55.327Z",
  "items": [{
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 1,
    "order": (need to be the order that i'm posting)
    "product": 1
  },
  {
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 12,
    "order": (need to be the order that i'm posting)
    "product": 3
  }]
}
```

But with my serializer the post are:

```
{
  "user": 10,
  "orderType": 1,
  "justification": "",
  "date": "2020-09-30T19:11:55.327Z",
  "items":{
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "product": 1
  }
}
```

There someway to do a serializer for the post inserting many items with the item.order field automatically setting (like the first json)?

#EDIT 1

To make more clear what I need after the solution of "many=True"...
Currently, if i wanna post an Order and an Item, I need first make a post of an order with a json like that:

```
{
  "user": 10,
  "orderType": 1,
  "justification": "",
  "date": "2020-09-30T19:11:55.327Z"
}
```

and then I need make a post for item with a json like that:

```
{
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "product": 1
}
```

in which the field "order" is the pk for Order that django automaticaly generate and return after the first post in my example.

How can I do a post with only one serializer for Ordem that contains many Items, if i don't know previaly the primary key for Ordem?
I belive that in my serializer i need override the "create" for set the Order primary key to my items, but i don't know how.

Basicaly, I need that my post work with the following json(without the field "order" in items, because the value for that is generate for django in an Order create):

```
{
  "user": 10,
  "orderType": 1,
  "justification": "",
  "date": "2020-09-30T19:11:55.327Z",
  "items": [{
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 1,
    "product": 1
  },
  {
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 12,
    "product": 3
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add many=True to the items = ItemSerializer() row:

```
items = ItemSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: Hi. Tkns for the solution. That worked for show all items.

Do you know how the post for this serializer automatically set the items.order for all items from my order?

The post expect the following json, that required in items the order id (I know the order id only after the order's post)

``` 
{
  "user": 0,
  "orderType": 0,
  "justification": "string",
  "date": "2020-10-04T19:37:49.713Z",
  "items": {
    "quantity": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "order": 0,
    "product": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply add the pk to your api view. For example if your api view is something like:

/api/orders_items_view/

You should go to /api/orders_items_view/3  where "3" is the pk of the order

Comment: Hi.
I thing that i don't was clear enough. By the way, sorry for my english.
I maked an edit to exemplifier better what i mean with make a post with only one serializer.

I don't know if your soluction would work because i don't have the order's pk to make the post request. (django automatically generate the pk only after the order's post)